# how to use loop at least 100 items in ion-select-option and bind in .ts file

Tags: angular, ionic4

i want to use at least  18 to 100 age list in ion select item using any loop.and with data binding in .ts file

```
<ion-item class="my-item5" > 
    <ion-icon name='podium' item-right color="gray"></ion-icon>
    <ion-label class="gen-col">Select age</ion-label>
    <ion-select value="age" okText="Ok" cancelText="Cancel">                                       
        <ion-select-option value="18">18</ion-select-option>
        <ion-select-option value="19">19</ion-select-option>
        <ion-select-option value="20">20</ion-select-option>
        <ion-select-option value="21">21</ion-select-option>
    </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do something like this:

```
<ion-item class="my-item5" > 
    <ion-icon name='podium' item-right color="gray"></ion-icon>
    <ion-label class="gen-col">Select age</ion-label>
    <ion-select value="age" okText="Ok" cancelText="Cancel">                                       
        <ion-select-option *ngFor="let number of [18,19,20,21,22,23] value="number">{{number}}</ion-select-option>
    </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

If you want to get rid of the `[18,19,20,...]` array, just create one using a for loop in the ts file and bind to that array.

For example like this:

```
let arr = [];
for (let i = 18; i < 100; i++) {
    arr.push(i);
}

this.ageList = arr;
```

Answer (score 0):

i found solution of above issues
in .htmnl

```
ion-select-option *ngFor="let age of ageList">{{age}}</ion-select-option>
```

in .ts

```
ageList:Array<any> = [];
this.ageList = Array.from({length:90},(v,k)=>k+18);
```